# CoordinatorLayout: overlapping Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I need to make overlapping effect on ImageButton and my BottomSheet, so bottom part of ImageButton will "hover" over part of my BottomSheet layout when it pops up.

Layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/but_location"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheetContainer"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="end"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:translationZ="@dimen/map_button_elevation"
                android:elevation="@dimen/map_button_elevation"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_icon"
                android:tint="@color/primary"
                style="@style/button.secondary" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/but_exit"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheetContainer"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="start"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:translationZ="@dimen/map_button_elevation"
                android:elevation="@dimen/map_button_elevation"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                style="@style/button.primary" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
                layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Desired effect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_gravity="top"` from your ImageButton this is attaching the ImageButton on top of bottom sheet.

Here is a sample code which i am using to achieve similar behavior.

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dummy" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/but_exit"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_secondary0"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheetContainer"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/but_location"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/material_dynamic_secondary0"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomSheetContainer"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:tint="@color/black" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Result before bottom sheet is expanded:]
[image: Result After bottom sheet is expanded:]